# Charms bar won't show

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, charms-bar

Implementing the settings charms bar. Following Michael Hauck's NuGet charmsflyout library.

**Success**: The 'About' button or link shows up in the settings charm. However -

**Problem**: The settings pane vanishes upon clicking 'About'

```
    private void CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var cmd = new SettingsCommand("about", "About This App", new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommandInvokedHandler(x =>
            {
                cfoSettings.IsOpen = true; // guessin problem is here??

            }));

        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(cmd);

        SettingsPane.Show();
    }
```

Xaml code:

```
    <cfo:CharmFlyout 
       x:Name="cfoSettings" 
       Heading="My Flyout" 
       HeadingBackgroundBrush="#FF4E0000">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock 
               FontSize="16">CharmFlyout by John Michael Hauck</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock 
               FontSize="16">For support:</TextBlock>

        </StackPanel>
    </cfo:CharmFlyout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made use of this and didn't have a single problem, perhaps you want to try this out instead?
[Flyout control for Windows 8 Metro Apps](http://kuchenzeit.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/flyout-control-for-windows-8-metro-xamlc/)